# Juice UI setup not working for me. what is missing?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, webforms

it may be really simple but i am not getting it right.

I am trying Juice UI with asp.net webforms (4.0) for the first time. I followed the below steps to start using it.

1. created a asp.net 4.0 web application
2. installed Juice UI from Nuget package.
3. JuiceUI dll is installed in bin and few more js files are also downloaded in the Script folder.
4. Added reference to the js/Css files in the page. (i dont have any master page)
5. added the UI code.

I get **Unknown server tag 'juice:Datepicker'.**
Am I missing something?

**Edit:** I also tried keeping ScriptManager in the page. didn't work. please help.

**Edit:** web.config looks like this.

```
<add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
```

Comment: @Aristos: Thanks! Web.config was updated when JuiceUi was installed using Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks like you do not have setup on web.config this tag. Here is what you need to have on your web.config according to this error.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If you have include this on your web.config the second think is that you have not include the .dll of this library on your bin

Comment: I have it in my web.config. I was little late in editing the post.

Comment: @PraveenLearnsEveryday Then you have missing the dll of it. Do you have include the JuiceUI.dll ? on the bin ?

Comment: Yes. I have juiceui.dll in my bin folder as well. Do we need scriptmanager too?

Comment: @PraveenLearnsEveryday I do not think so about scriptmanager. Do you have any other errors before that ? because if you have this, and the dll and you get this error is means that the dll is not loaded.

Comment: thanks for your interest. I got the solution. It needs the scriptmanager tag in your page. moreover my dll name was conflicting with project name (i named my project JuiceUI) it works like charm now.

Answer (score 2):

After check that your web.config has the following Juice Information.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <pages>
     <controls>
       <add assembly="JuiceUI" namespace="Juice" tagPrefix="juice" />
     </controls>
   </pages>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Just build your project (press F6) to have the JuiceUI.dll copied to your Bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

You may be missing jquery references

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Scripts>
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" />
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js" />
</Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```